# Verbatim in Marginnote doesn't work

Tags: verbatim, marginpar

I have a really sort quastion.
The following Code is not working:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore gubergren. \marginnote{\verb?\documentclass{memoir}?}%%% --- does not work!!!

\verb?\documentclass{memoir}?%%% it is working, looks pretty

\end{document}
```

I would like to write something like a package description, a manual that's why I would like to create marginnotes.

The Problem what I get is the following:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8
```

---

#### UPDATE

First of all, Thanks for the quick answers ;)

I tested both packages. I find really good the fancyvbr package, it can give me much more as I taught. The cprotect package works also good, BUT
If I leave a bracket in the Verbatim text -- like here:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cprotect\marginnote{\verb?}?}
```

-- then it does not work, I get the message too many {'...
Otherwise it's working in the normal text, but not with marginnote

SaveVerb can be a solution, it's working, but I don't want 300 saved Verbatims :-)

So I don't really know what to do...

Some idea?

Comment: @user3097: I think your update really should be a new question since the original question was solved. After posting a new question (and linking to this one), you should make a rollback here. (By the way, may I ask what a "really sort quastion" is? `:-)`)

Comment: @user3097: The shortcoming of cprotect that you describe is documented (otherwise, I need to add it to the documentation): when reading `\cprotect\marginnote{\verb?}?}`, the `\cprotect` command thinks that the argument is `\verb?`. It has no way of knowing that the closing brace is to be skipped before actually executing `\verb`. And then it is too late. Two workarounds: `\cprotect\marginnote{\iffalse{\fi\verb?}?}` or `\cprotect\marginnote{%{` <newline> `\verb?}?}`.

Comment: You could also decide to use both: SaveVerb the pieces that have non-balanced braces, and simply cprotect the rest.

Comment: @user3097: I still think you should follow my advice above. Then you'll have a chance of getting the question in your update answered. It would also make your question appear less cluttered.

Comment: Great that you changed your user name. Maybe you clean this post up a bit if I keep nagging? `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fancyvrb` package defines the `\SaveVerb` command and `SaveVerbatim` environment that can be used for that purpose.  In fact, an example in the manual for that package talks about that very situation:

```
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\SaveVerb{Verb}|_OK^|
\marginpar{\UseVerb{Verb}}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can for example use the package [`cprotect`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cprotect/), which provides the command `\cprotect` for precisely this type of use. In your case, use

```
\cprotect\marginnote{\verb?\documentclass{memoir}?}
```

Namely,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore gubergren. \cprotect\marginnote{\verb?\documentclass{memoir}?}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the new version of my `newverbs` package to define a verbatim margin note macro. It gives you the same interface as `\verb<char>...<char>` but also `{...}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/23]
\newcommand*{\verbmarginnote}{\collectverb{\marginnote}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore gubergren. \verbmarginnote|\documentclass{memoir}|
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the code, and it's working well. What do you think, how could I use instead \marginnote the \sidepar command? It works with memoir class better. Otherwise I found commands in the memoir class like \cs{} and \oarg and \marg. These commands are specially for documentations. They base on the command \char'. In this case, it is also a solution, but not for verbatims with more rows.

Comment: You could write `\texttt{\textbackslash documentclass\{memoir\}}` instead to avoid the issue with verbatim and place it in any other macro you want. That is what `\cs` etc. basically does.