# \listings environment inside \marginnote?

Tags: listings, margins, marginpar, marginnote

Is it possible to use `\listings` or similar environment inside `\marginnote` or in margins in general?

```
\marginnote{
    \begin{lstlisting}
        test
    \end{lstlisting}
}
```

If not, what would be a workaround if I wanted to simply put coding notes in margins?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/verbatim-in-marginnote-doesnt-work

Comment: Yes, that works, but sadly requires to individually save each `Verbatim`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my take with the `listings` package. The code below defines a new environment via `\lstnewenvironment` that saves the listing in a box and then typesets it in a `\marginpar` (or `\marginnote` if you like):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=5cm,includemp,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\newbox\marginlst
\newlength\marginlstoffset
% framerule + framesep + rulesep:
\setlength\marginlstoffset{\dimexpr2mm+3pt+2pt\relax}

\lstnewenvironment{marginlisting}
  {%
    \lstset{
      basicstyle = \small\ttfamily,
      frame = leftline ,
      framerule = 2mm ,
      rulecolor = \color{black!20},
      breaklines = true ,
      linewidth = \dimexpr\marginparwidth-\marginlstoffset\relax
    }%
    \setbox\marginlst\hbox\bgroup
  }
  {%
    \egroup
    % or \marginnote:
    \marginpar{\hspace*{\marginlstoffset}\unhbox\marginlst}%
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Some initial words
\begin{marginlisting}
BEGIN
    FOR k IN c2(o.id) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('test');
    END LOOP;
END.
\end{marginlisting}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

With `fancyvrb` you can use an environment form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=5cm,includemp]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote,fancyvrb,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\marginlistingbox}
\newenvironment{marginlisting}
  {\fvset{tabsize=3,frame=leftline,framerule=2mm,rulecolor=\color{black!20}}%
   \setbox\marginlistingbox=\vtop\bgroup
     \hsize=\marginparwidth
     \topsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt
     \vspace*{-1.4\baselineskip}%
     \Verbatim}
  {\endVerbatim\egroup\marginnote{\leavevmode\box\marginlistingbox}}

\begin{document}
Some initial words%
\begin{marginlisting}
BEGIN
    FOR k IN c2(o.id) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('test');
    END LOOP;
END.
\end{marginlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've little hope you can do it with `listings`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>So in the end I went with the `fancyvrb` solution as [John Wickerson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25356/john-wickerson) pointed out.</strike> It seems that for small code snippets to be used in margins it's quite useful (although there's no keywording feature that I know of)

```
% set options globally
\fvset{tabsize=3,frame=leftline,framerule=2mm,rulecolor=\color{black!20}} 

% define and save
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{name} 
BEGIN
    FOR k IN c2(o.id) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('test');
    END LOOP;
END.
\end{SaveVerbatim}

% use it
\marginnote{\UseVerbatim{name}}

... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
```

gives:

[image: Verbatim_result]

[fancyvrb at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb)